# Two different namespaces connect to a same event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have two namespaces namely
 **'/'** , **/notification**

Suppose I fire an event in '/' namespace, How do I access/listen to the same event in '/notification' namespace . It would be really great if someone explains the answer to this question with an example.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `socket.io` for this, then [this article](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-multiplexing) should help. It shows you some of the ways you could connect to other namespaces, with queries, etc. Basically, for you, it bubbles down to this:

```js
// Connect to the "/" namespace
const socket = io("/");
// Connect to the "/notification" namespace
const notificationSocket = io("/notification", {
  // Uncomment this if you want two connections
  // By default, socket.io re-uses the existing connection
  // to communicate with the other namespace
  // forceNew: true
});

// Code and stuff
```

Hope this helps you:)

Comment: Hey,can you explain it with a random event as an example please?

Comment: @loksan, so, let me get this straight...  Do you want to listen for an event that happens in the "/" namespace while you are connected **only** to the "notification" namespace?

Comment: Yeahh that's what I wanted!